# gitlab pages connot visit directly, it need do a login to gitlab

Tags: html, gitlab, gitlab-pages

I found a problem, the new project with gitlab pages connot directly visit, it need the visitor login a gitlab account. 
but the old gitlab repo with gitlab pages can visit directly without any login information.

for example when I visit https://shanghai-massage.gitlab.io/emily_massage
it will jump to https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in

when I visit the old repo pages https://shanghai-massage.gitlab.io/jenny_massage
it will directly show the html pages

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer from gitlab surport, they changed the access control!

```
Tristan Williams (GitLab, Inc.)
Nov 3, 22:46 EST

Hey there,

Thanks for contacting GitLab Support.

You most likely need to adjust the access level of the Pages portion of the repository associated with that GitLab Pages site, since we recently enabled access control for Pages on GitLab.com. To do so, navigate to Settings -> General -> Visibility, project features, permissions and toggle the Pages access to Everyone with access.

All the best,

Tristan Williams
GitLab, Inc.
```